# Jquery Mobile - including fragments for a multipage template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-mobile

We're doing a Codeigniter/jQM web application and have been debating the multipage template vs. single-page/file.

Most of the cons of the multi-page template (meaning multiple data-role=page divs in a single file) cited relate to the single file getting unwieldy from a maintenance (and possible load time) perspective.  The cons of the single-page approach seem to mostly focus on potential latency between pages.  Given the vagaries of the internet, the latter approach seems more risky.  It is my opinion that a user will tolerate a long load time if the app runs smoothly once loaded much more than an app that is inconsistent between touches/swipes.

That being said, we have a growing team of folks who are working on various parts of the app and having one, huge file presents a challenge -- even for Git.

So, my question is this:

Is there a reason we can't we break up the multi-page template into separate files, each containing the `<div data-role=page>` and all its contents, and just -include- each one in the main file?  That would seem to solve the maintenance issue and alleviate the potential delay between page transitions.

What am I missing, here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is no.  It works fine.